# Sort elements with specific order in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

How can I sort it by custom order?

Input:

```
[
    {value: "typeA"},
    {value: "typeC"},
    {value: "typeB"},
    {value: "typeC"},
    {value: "typeB"},
    {value: "typeA"}
]
```

Expect result:

```
[
    {value: "typeB"},
    {value: "typeB"},
    {value: "typeC"},
    {value: "typeC"},
    {value: "typeA"},
    {value: "typeA"}
]

my_own_order = ['typeB', 'typeC', 'typeA']
```

My python code as following right now:

```
result = sorted(input, key=lambda v:v['value'])
```

Comment: Given `input`, `result` are not valid Python literals. If you mean dictionaries, they should be `{"xxx1": {"value": "typeA"}, "xxx2": {"value": "typeC"}, ...}` format.

Comment: Sorry, update my ``input`` and ``result``

Comment: It's just an example. For example: sort by specific list of items ``type``.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [
...     {'value': "typeA"},
...     {'value': "typeC"},
...     {'value': "typeB"},
...     {'value': "typeC"},
...     {'value': "typeB"},
...     {'value': "typeA"}
... ]
>>> my_own_order = ['typeB', 'typeC', 'typeA']
```

---

Make a mapping between `typeB`, `typeC`, `typeA` to 0, 1, 2

```
>>> order = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(my_own_order)}
>>> order
{'typeA': 2, 'typeC': 1, 'typeB': 0}
```

And use the mapping for sorting key:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda d: order[d['value']])
[{'value': 'typeB'},
 {'value': 'typeB'},
 {'value': 'typeC'},
 {'value': 'typeC'},
 {'value': 'typeA'},
 {'value': 'typeA'}]
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
sorted(input, key=lambda v: my_own_order.index(v['value']))
```

Comment: You have a typo, the code should be: 
`sorted(input, key=lambda v: my_own_order.index(v[value]))`
(No quotation around 'value')

Comment: Note that this method does a linear search for every item.

Answer (score 1):

Taking an input and set the order in my_order and it will print in that order

```
enter code here

user_input = input()
my_order = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1357902468'
print(*sorted(user_input, key=my_order.index),sep='')
```