# Django Query Sort by Value of String

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I have a model that allows my client to create menus for his restaurant.  Everything works great except I would like to set the explicit ordering by the string value of a model.  For instance; he is creating sections like Salads, Pastas, Pizzas etc.. but they are displayed through the template in the order they are added to the system.  How can I add a sort to my query that I can set the order manually?  Below is my current snippet.

I am using
Django 1.10.5, Wagtail 1.9, Python 3.5x

## Snippet

```
@register.inclusion_tag('tags/_lunch-menu-list.html', takes_context=True)
def lunch_products(context):
    sections = Section.objects.all().prefetch_related('product').filter(product__lunch_menu=True).distinct()
    return {
        'sections': sections,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Django queryset has a mechanism to order by a list of field value.

Option 1:
Order in Python. Keep it mind it will return a list, not a queryset anymore (inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308635/sort-elements-with-specific-order-in-python)) and that you end up using magic strings (what if the user uses `Entrées` instead of `Starters`?):

```
sections = Section.objects.all()
order = ['Starters', 'Salads', 'Desserts']
order = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(order)}
ordered_sections = sorted(sections, key=lambda section: order.get(section.name, 0))
```

Option 2:
Add a `menu_order` integer field on the `Section` object and `order_by` on this field. This is not the best UX though since you'll need to edit each section to set the order and will have to remember what number you've used for each of them.

Option 3:
Create a `Menu` object with [orderable](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/reference/pages/model_reference.html?highlight=Orderable#orderable-abstract) sections (see [how they order carousel item](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtaildemo/blob/fe6102eee2e81d0e489a8dd5dd7407b3343c04de/demo/models.py#L213-L214) in the demo app), but this looks a bit overkill for you since it seems you will always ever have 1 order.

Comment: Since my clients menu sections are static and not likely to change, I added an order field, did an ordering in the model meta, then opened the database and manually added the ordering there instead of making it visible in modeladmin.  This allowed me to order the sections in a slightly hackish way without the client having to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) to sort query sets. For example, if you have a `name` attribute in your models, you'd just add `.order_by("name")` to the end of your query.

Comment: Thats just going to order_by() alphabetically; I need something like order_by(name=['Starters', 'Salads', 'Desserts'..... etc... ])