# How to a sort list in the given alphabetical order using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Inputs:

```
Alpha = ['d', 'c', 'a', 'b']
words = ['dda', 'bdb', 'adc', 'cdd']
```

How do I sort words in the order of Alpha to get the following result?

```
words = ['dda', 'cdd', 'adc', 'bdb']
```

Could you please me on how to do this?

Here I am trying to sort a list but not the dictionary keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort elements with specific order in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308635/sort-elements-with-specific-order-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sort the words lexicographically based on your order specified in `alpha`, by making a list of indices for each word (which [Python then compares lexicographically](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types))

```
def sort_key(w):
    return [alpha.index(ch) for ch in w]

words.sort(key=sort_key)
```

There are likely to be more efficient solutions that store the key in a hash (as in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308635/sort-elements-with-specific-order-in-python)).

An alternative would be to turn your `alpha` into a [`string.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) translation table.

```
ascii_characters = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(256))
translation = string.maketrans(''.join(alpha), ascii_characters[:len(alpha)])
words.sort(key=lambda w: w.translate(translation))
```

An advantage of this way is that you can put the translations into a dictionary for (possibly) greater speed.

```
order = {w: w.translate(translation) for w in words}
words.sort(key=lambda w: order[w]))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sorted function with key:

```
>>> Alpha = ['d', 'c', 'a', 'b']
>>> words = ['dda', 'bdb', 'adc', 'cdd']
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda x:Alpha.index(x[0]))
['dda', 'cdd', 'adc', 'bdb']
```

Comment: Try with different combination of words, it wont work I think

Comment: words = ['dda', 'dbdb', 'dadc', 'dcdd']

Comment: ok, sorting should work through whole word not only the 1st character

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, it will sort according to alpha index of first letter.

```
alpha = ['d', 'c', 'a', 'b']
words = ['dda', 'bdb', 'adc', 'cdd']
words.sort(key=lambda x: alpha.index(x[0]))
```

Output:

> "dda" "cdd"   "adc"   "bdb"

Comment: Try with different combination of words, it wont work I think

Comment: Try with http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and show me an example then:)

Comment: @Beri OP want lexicographical sort base on alpha, it should not only restrict to 1st char.

Comment: you are sorting with just first letter, please get it sorted with all chars