# How to sort filename list based on predefined order from another list after matching patterns?

Tags: python, list, sorting, arcpy

I'm trying to sort a list of raster (`rasters`)

```
 rasters = '["example\\\\alt_canal.tif", "example\\\\back_garden.tif", "example\\\\main_entrance.tif", "example\\\\my_ditch.tif", "example\\\\ne_lawn.tif"]'
```

based on pattern matching and predefined order (`ras_order`).

```
ras_order = '["ditch", "canal", "entrance", "garden", "lawn"]'
```

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308635/sort-elements-with-specific-order-in-python) but it didn't give me what I wanted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Expected output:

> [u'example\my_ditch.tif', u'example\alt_canal.tif', u'example\main_entrance.tif', u'example\back_garden.tif', u'example\ne_lawn.tif']

Sample code:

```
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")  

# set project directory
working_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/')
scenario = 'example'
env.workspace = os.path.join(working_dir, scenario)

# predefined order
ras_order = ['ditch', 'canal', 'entrance', 'garden', 'lawn']

# find rasters in the working_dir 
rasters = []  
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(os.path.join(working_dir, scenario), topdown=True, datatype="RasterDataset")  
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:  
    for filename in filenames:  
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))  

print(rasters)

# [u'example\\alt_canal.tif', u'example\\back_garden.tif', u'example\\main_entrance.tif', u'example\\my_ditch.tif', u'example\\ne_lawn.tif']

# sort based on predefined order (not working)
new_order1 = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(ras_order, rasters))]
print(new_order1)

# [u'example\\back_garden.tif', u'example\\alt_canal.tif', u'example\\main_entrance.tif', u'example\\my_ditch.tif', u'example\\ne_lawn.tif']
```

In addition to @Lante's answer, here is another way to do it:

```
new_raster = []
for i in ras_order:
    for j in rasters:
        if i in j:
            new_raster.append(j)
new_raster

[u'example\\\\Max (dec).my_ditch.tif',
 u'example\\\\Max (dec).alt_canal.tif',
 u'example\\\\Max (dec).main_entrance.tif',
 u'example\\\\Max (dec).back_garden.tif',
 u'example\\\\Max (dec).ne_lawn.tif']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple solution, to be refined with regex for a more precise matching:

```
rasters = ["example\\\\alt_canal.tif", "example\\\\back_garden.tif", "example\\\\main_entrance.tif", "example\\\\my_ditch.tif", "example\\\\ne_lawn.tif"]
ras_order = ["ditch", "canal", "entrance", "garden", "lawn"]

def ras_match(r, o):
    return next(i for i, x in enumerate(o) if x in r)

sorted(rasters, key=lambda x: ras_match(x, ras_order))
```

Output:

```
['example\\\\my_ditch.tif',
 'example\\\\alt_canal.tif',
 'example\\\\main_entrance.tif',
 'example\\\\back_garden.tif',
 'example\\\\ne_lawn.tif']
```